Intermittent ingress nginx upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream
This is NOT "while reading resp*nse header from upstream" and the issue is NOT a slow response from  the upstream server.
I did this curl:
curl https://knotfree.net/api1/getGiantPassword
What I get is a 5 second delay. What I expect is no delay, the same as this curl:
curl http://knotfree.io/api1/getGiantPassword
If I restart the ingress-nginx pod then the first request completes normally. After that it goes like this. I curl:
curl https://knotfree.net/api1/getGiantPassword
Then nginx wait for 5 long lonely seconds before coming to the conclusion:
2024/07/06 18:35:06 [error] 26#26: *556202 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.3.96.7, server: knotfree.net, request: "GET /api1/getGiantPassword HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[fd10:1ba:6d2c:1000:3a5b:26d5:2b5f:56b6]:8085/api1/getGiantPassword", host: "knotfree.net"
And then the fun part. It sends the request to the upstream; which logs the request; and then replies in a millisecond; and then nginx logs:
10.3.96.7 - - [06/Jul/2024:18:45:10 +0000] "GET /api1/getGiantPassword HTTP/2.0" 200 79 "-" "curl/8.6.0" 46 5.002 [knotspace-knotfreeaide-80] [] [fd10:1ba:6d2c:1000:3a5b:26d5:2b5f:56b6]:8085, 10.244.183.182:8085 0, 79 5.000, 0.002 504, 200 6e1e1ab19b8964722f112dc49e642238
Which is a 200 and curl shows the correct output (basically a random number).
How is nginx both having an error and also serving the correct result? Why does it sometimes work perfectly?
Note that the ingress-nginx controller is doing the https termination. My other, non-secure endpoint works perfectly always:
curl http://knotfree.io/api1/getGiantPassword
What does it mean that it can't connect with upstream? Am I supposed to be serving a health check?
This is on vultr kubernetes.
FYI. Here's the Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "knotfree.net"  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-dns01-provider: vultr
    
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "knotfree.net" 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: knotfreeaide
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: "*.knotfree.net" 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: knotfreeaide
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "knotfree.net"
    - "*.knotfree.net"
    secretName: wildcard-tls


The workaround is to start an nginx pod and service and have the ingress send traffic to the nginx service and then have the nginx pod proxy to my service (knotfreeaide).  I will need to figure out what the nginx service is doing that I'm not because this approach is not suitable for production.
